# How to replace ActionBarDrawerToggle on right hand side in place of stackoverflow icon

Tags: java, android, mmdrawercontroller

How to replace ActionBarDrawerToggle on right hand side in place of stackoverflow icon?
I have placed drawer layout from right to left button toolbar `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` is appearing on left hand side how to get it right:

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) { 
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) { 
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
             mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT); 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Used above code to get drawer from left to right.

Toolbar `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` is on left side and drawer coming from right side. How to get toolbar `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` also on right side?

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT))
            {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            else
            {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
        return false;
    } used above code to get drawer from left to right

Comment: problem resolved ? then why not updated your question ? update it in spite of new comment.

Comment: not solved yet 
toolbar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); is on left side and drawer coming from right side
how to get toolbar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  also on right side

Comment: You are creating app for right to left i mean language like urdu or arabic ? if not then home menu will not come on right you have to inflate menu on right hand side and use stackoverflow icon over there and on click of that open drawer from right side.